# Query invoices that have more than one transaction associated with them

Tags: mysql, sql

The table below contains payment transactions with each having an invoiceID. I'm trying write a query to list the invoiceID's that have more than one transaction associated with them.

```
    mysql> describe tblaccounts;
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| userid      | int(10)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date        | datetime      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| description | text          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| amount      | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | 0.00    |                |
| transid     | text          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| invoiceid   | int(10)       | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

From what I've read I should be using a combination of 'GROUP BY' and 'HAVING' but I don't understand how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT invoiceid
FROM tblaccounts
GROUP BY invoiceid HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

You can use sth like this. First group by invoice id. Now we have groups that have same invoiceid. Then we select the groups whose count more than one with **HAVING** keyword. For more information check here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp and here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT invoiceid FROM tblaccounts GROUP BY invoiceid HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```